# Inverse Arc Length of a Parabola

Tags: inverse-function, lambert-w, arc-length

Is the inverse for the arc length of a parabola (say, $f(x)=\dfrac{x^2}{2}$) not discovered, or not possible to express given elementary functions and product log ($W(x)$)? If the latter is so, is there a proof?

I ask because Wolfram Alpha offers not an expression, even using the product log, of the inverse arc length $L$ of a parabola of the simplest form: the inverse of $$ L=\frac{x\sqrt{1+x^2}}2+\frac{\ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})}2.$$

I've also seen other questions of a similar nature, but none address ***why*** there is no inverse; is it a lack of an ingenious way to find it or a lack of possibility (or a lack of an ingenious proof of the latter)

Comment: Is the parabola equation to which the above is the arc length correct? Do want that, if arc length is given whether $x$ can be found out? Please feel free to roll back my edit  to improve the question.

Comment: Yes, the question is in regards to finding a function that maps arc lengths to their respective x-values, and not to the original quadratic. However, the actual coefficient is somewhat arbitrary; x^2/2 simply has the most compact arc length expression.